# Selecionar um produto por estabelecimento no banco mysql!

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados com as tabelas `estabelecimentos` e `produtos`. Cadastro os produtos relacionando-os com os estabelecimentos.

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde selecione somente um produto de cada estabelecimento, pensei em fazer com LIMIT mas me parece que não vai funcionar.

Exemplo: se tenho 10 estabelecimentos e 100 produtos, quero uma consulta que me retorne 10 produtos mas sendo um de cada estabelecimento.

[image: Colunas das tabelas]

Comment: Adicione o schema das suas tabelas na pergunta para facilitar a resposta.

Comment: Adicionei, se tiver mais alguma dúvida é só falar. Obrigado

Comment: Acho que funciona sim com `LIMIT`, pode colocar em um `for` que indica o id do estabelecimento (ou fazer manual) e pesquisar `SELECT * FROM produto WHERE ID_estab = $cont-or-id LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `group by`, ficaria algo assim

```
SELECT * FROM produto GROUP BY ID_estab
```

**Edit**

Se você quiser exibir 1 produto randômico de cada estabelecimento

```
SELECT p.* FROM (SELECT * FROM produto ORDER BY RAND()) as p GROUP BY p.ID_estab
```

Comment: Vai funcionar? Não precisa especificar a coluna no `GROUP BY`?

Comment: No exemplo já está especificando `GROUP BY ID_estab`, que seria a coluna `ID_estab`

Comment: Nessa consulta precisa utilizar a coluna `ID_estab` pois não esta fazendo `JOIN` para utilizar a coluna `IdEstab` da tabela `estabelecimento`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeito, valeu mesmo!